# Android toolbar night theme stuck on default color

Tags: android, android-dark-theme

When the user activated the system night mode, the toolbar color changes in material dark so the actionbar background is #121212.

night/themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#0069D3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#0069D3</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">#006BD5</item>
    <item name="colorOnSurface">#006BD5</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">#006BD5</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorToolbar</item>
    <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.AppBarOverlay</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.AppBarOverlay</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.ActionBarNight</item>
    </style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="backgroundColor">#006BD5</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorToolbar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorToolbar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.ActionBarNight" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">?attr/colorToolbar</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorToolbar</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The example activity XML doesn't contain any Toolbar.

Example activity by manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ProblemiMateriale"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp" />
```